# Unavailable Modifiers When Using Hierarchal List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

When using a pattern similar to

```
List {
  ForEach() {}
}
```

ForEach accepts modifiers such as .onDelete and .onMove.

However, when making a hierarchal list with a pattern similar to

```
List(items, children: \.children) { row in
}
```

nothing appears to accept those modifiers.  How does one add these modifiers to the leaf elements in the tree?

Comment: `onDelete(perform:)`  and `onMove(perform:)`  are the properties of [DynamicViewContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicviewcontent) protocol and ForEach conforms `DynamicViewContent`, but List does not.